# Is Organising Test Suite in inheritance hierarchy for DRY a bad thing? What alternatives are there?

Tags: unit-testing, dry, code-duplication

I develop a system which:

- accepts http requests with sometimes complex json arguments
- sanitizes the arguments
- loads data from database
- checks conditions based on both
- sends execution requests to remote executors
- checks the content of response and depending on it (and http request arguments and data loaded from db) does some action
- etc.

My problem is that some methods that implement business logic just have a long OK case flow. The business logic is just complex and there doesn't seem to be any reasonable way to move some functionality to a different class. I want to write unit tests that will test all branches in this class. The first tests that cover the arguments checks are simple - just call and expect the exception. After covering first NOK cases, I continue further to NOK cases with a bit of setup code  that pass first checks, call first mock and fail on 2nd checks. I also add some verify there. There are a few ways how execution can fail at this "stage" so each has its own test. Then I do the same for yet another "stage" of the flow. Again adding another layer of setup at the beginning and verify at the end getting closer and closer to the full OK case. The ok case flow has 8-12 "stages" and after each step there are multiple possible NOK case outcomes.

Long story short, I end up with many tests that have duplicated code that comes in "layers" of setup and verify code with each "stage". I remember watching Clean Code episodes where Uncle Bob said that a good way to handle such things is to organize tests in inheritance hierarchy, with each more advanced test inheriting the setup and tear down (verify) of the previous one. This seems to work well with regard to DRY principle for me, however it impacts negatively on tests readability. I have also read many opinions that inheriting is a bad way to organize your test suite.

Do you have any tips or patterns how to better organize such kind of tests? How do you structure your test suites that need to handle similar business logic?

Comment: I write helper methods, or sometimes separate helper classes, that deal with repeating parts of the setup. For example, I just call a method like `GivenSomeBladieBlahInMyDB(7)`, which sets up a mock for the database with a 7 random test Bladieblahs. Each of the tests that requires this setup to get to the right point in the testes method can just call this method as part of the setup.

Comment: Alternatively, you can write one such method that sets up everyting to reach OK. In each NOK test, you can call this method, and then break one piece of the setup to test for that particular NOK.

Comment: The thins is that often a setup layer comes with a tear down later. For example in Java this  is often a when/given mock setup before call to SUT and then verify after the call to SUT. This is why it makes inheritance so fitting here - because you can pair setup and tear down parts and make sure they are put on and peeled off always together

Comment: Thats true, but if things get more complex inheritance gets you stuck. In one test you need A, in the next you need A and B, so you derive it from the first, so far so good. And then you get tests that needs ABC, ACD or BD, and suddenly you can only build it using multiple inheritance..  Composition, using helper objects to set up tests, which you use from different, independent tests, would have my preference. But that's what it is, preference. You can do it any way you want. If you like the inheritance setup, by all means use it.